# Change character to dates

Tags: r

Been search for an answer to my question but can't solve my issue.
I have a very large dataset of variables V1 to V31 signifying the 31 days in July. Looks something like this:

> Name         Date
>         
> 1 A            V1
> 2 A            V2
> 3 B            V1
> 4 B            V2
> 5 C            V1
> 6 C            V2

Every 'Name' has variables going from V1 to V31. I want to change V1:V31 to March 1st: March 31. I've tried using a vector of all the days in March but I have way more rows than 31 so this turns up an error.

I've been trying to assign V1= March 1, V2= March 2nd, but have been running into data issues. I'm not sure how to use the as.Date function in this context to change char to dttm. Please help!

Comment: Can you please share reproducible example using dput() function in R?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this `base R` approach. If you want some month you can create a dataframe and store all the dates on it, then format the dates as you want and define an index for matching based on `V` values. Here the code:

```
#Create a dataframe for dates
df.dates <- data.frame(Date = seq(as.Date('2020-03-01'),as.Date('2020-03-31'),by = '1 day'))
#Format dates and build index V
df.dates$Formated <- format(df.dates$Date,'%b %d')
df.dates$Index <- paste0('V',1:nrow(df.dates))
#Now match with df
df$Value <- df.dates[match(df$Date,df.dates$Index),"Formated"]
```

Output:

```
df
  Name Date  Value
1    A   V1 Mar 01
2    A   V2 Mar 02
3    B   V1 Mar 01
4    B   V2 Mar 02
5    C   V1 Mar 01
6    C   V2 Mar 02
```

Some data used:

```
#Data
df <- structure(list(Name = c("A", "A", "B", "B", "C", "C"), Date = c("V1", 
"V2", "V1", "V2", "V1", "V2")), row.names = c("1", "2", "3", 
"4", "5", "6"), class = "data.frame")
```